# How to cache NSFetchRequest results without NSFetchedResultsController?

Tags: iphone, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nsfetchrequest

**Is there a way to cache NSFetchRequest results, but without using an NSFetchedResultsController?** I know how to set the cache name for the results controller, but in a number of instances I just pull data from my core data store and want to cache it -- but have no need for a results controller. Any ideas on how to do this? I can't find anything in Apple's documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can keep it in memory in an NSArray.  If you want to cache between executions of your application you can't.  That portion of the `NSFetchedResultsController` is not published and the internal structure of Core Data is not open.

If a cache is absolutely needed then use a `NSFetchedResultsController`.

However, considering the speed and performance of Core Data, I would question the absolute *need* for a cache.  I suspect performance can be gained in other areas.